# how to pull unique results

Tags: sql, mysql, hibernate

im looking for query to load and group the data

i do have 1:n relationship of Parent:Child

and i want to  pull latest child,instead of children, of a parent

that means each entry should have unique parent with latest child.

**Child Table** 
[image]

**Desired Results**
[image]

Tried:

i have tried following query but it get me oldest results

```
SELECT c.* FROM child  AS c GROUP BY c.parent_id HAVING(MAX(c.order))
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select ct.*
    from ChildTable ct
        inner join (select parent_id, max(order) as MaxOrder
                        from ChildTable
                        group by parent_id) q
            on ct.parent_id = q.parent_id
                and ct.order= q.MaxOrder
```

Comment: sorry to say, it dont work because it get me more than 2 rows.There must be two rows

Comment: If that's showing the correct results, add `ORDER BY ct.createdDate LIMIT 1` to the end of the query and that'll get you what you need

Comment: @Rehman: How would you want to resolve ties, such as the case where `createdDate` is the same for all 4 entries of `parent_id` 2?

Comment: @Joe: okay i accept the createdDate in child table for parent2 is same what about the parent_1. let me post you another image with changed dates.

Comment: @Rehman: So, when you say you want the "latest" child, it looks like you want to define "latest" based on the `order` column instead of the `createdDate` column that I used. Is that correct?

Comment: @Joe: you are free to both columns to get expected results.

Comment: @Rehman: Edited my answer. See if this version works better for you.